# SublimeText plugin: making new view the active view

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am writing a plugin for Sublime Text and am trying to run some view commands in a newly opened tab (those commands are in playback_text). However, the code below is executing the else statement. Am I missing something about focusing the view? Before calling run_command, I want the application to be focused on the new view.

```
class PlayInNewWindowCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        newView = self.window.new_file()
        sublime.active_window().focus_view(newView)
        if sublime.active_window().active_view() == newView:
            newView.run_command("playback_text")
        else:
            print sublime.windows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code you provided with a very slight modification of my own (show a dialog box instead of running the "playback_text" command). 
When I ran the command, it opened a new file and executed the if statement. Ignored the else statement. Not sure if you ran the command correctly. Also, you haven't included the import statement above your command so not sure if you have imported the required modules. Like this

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
```

Here is the code I just ran:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class PlayInNewWindowCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        newView = self.window.new_file()
        sublime.active_window().focus_view(newView)
        if sublime.active_window().active_view() == newView:
            sublime.message_dialog("new view is active view")
        else:
            print (sublime.windows())
```